# PHP Warning: PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library (PDO)

Tags: php, mysql, dll, pdo

I had using laravel, elequant orm and I have no problem till today. Today I start a php script with pdo. But I couldn't any insert with pdo. I checked my php.ini file and I removed semicolon from `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll'. Nothing changed, still I cant create any insert with pdo.

Also in laravel, when I said `php artisan tinker`, it gives me below error ?

> PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_firebird.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_firebird.dll: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0 PHP Warning:  PHP
>   Startup: Unable to load dynamic library
>   '/usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_mysql.dll' -
>   /usr/lib/php/20160303/php_pdo_mysql.dll: cannot open shared object
>   file: No such file or directory in Unknown on line 0

What is the problem in here ? (And yes I said that `sudo service apache2 restart` everytime)

Comment: Your doing it wrong, add the `;` back to `extension=php_pdo_mysql.dll` linux does not use `dlls`, then run `sudo apt install php7.0-mysql`, restart apache.

Comment: or `php7.1-mysql`  depending on your php version, do `apt search php*-mysql` to find out for sure.

Comment: then, how to use pdo ?

Comment: I'm confused, I thought the question was fixing a broken php.ini file and installing PDO extension, not how to use PDO. Laravel has docs for that.

Comment: Well, you are right but I just didin't want to create new question for that

Comment: No probs, I don't use laravel its bloated and slow, anyways you can find out what you need from here: https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/database